# Using Apache HTTPClient - how can one see the raw request string before it's being sent?

Tags: apache-commons-httpclient

For debugging purposes, I'd like to see the raw request that is going to be sent. Is there a way to get this without a HTTP monitor directly from the API of [`HttpPost`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpHost.html?is-external=true) or [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)?

I found some "almost" duplicate questions, but not for this particular one

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set some environment variables for Apache HttpClient (example tested for 4.3.2).

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire", "DEBUG");
```

There are also some more variables for debugging:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.conn", "DEBUG");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.client", "DEBUG");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.client", "DEBUG");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "DEBUG");
```

Comment: For more logging options depending on your environment, see https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: @Eran Medan  There is also the HttpRequestInterceptor if you want to do it for a specific requuest

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request#viaProxy
```

This method can make your request pass through proxy server, so your can launch a local proxy server, for example Fiddler, so this debugging proxy can show the details of http request and response.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling `DEBUG` mode in your logging configurations, if you're using `log4j` you can add this to the `log4j.xml` file of your project

```
<root>
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

You will have the full request headers, params, body, etc, logged in your logs files.

Answer (score 0):

## log4j2 and/or slf4j solution

For everybody using log4j2 and/or slf4j all the mentioned solutions didn't work.
I added the following to my maven pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add a log4j2.xml file / or use your existing one and add:

```
    <Logger name="org.apache.http">
        <Level>DEBUG</Level>
    </Logger>
```

Of course for a valid log4j2.xml configuration you need some appenders defined etc. A simple example can be [found here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);

method.setParameter(...., ....);
```

to retrieve the URI

```
System.out.println("getUri: " + method.getURI());
```

to retrieve the parameters in POST

```
method.getRequestEntity().writeRequest(System.out);
```

Comment: System.out is not to be encouraged for logging

Comment: I liked this example, because `method.getRequestEntity().writeRequest` helped me to print out the request.

Comment: @MitchKent While I agree, I disagree polluting a minimal example with irrelevant logging code.

Comment: This is impractical for anything outside of a demo. Can you imagine doing this for every single HTTP call made?