# log4j 2 not showing dependency logs

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using apache HttpClient to execute a POST request:

`CloseableHttpResponse response = HttpClients.createDefault().execute(request);`

I want to see the request (and other apache client library log statements) in the logs, but I can only see my application logs, no other logs from any dependency.

Here is my `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Lambda name="Lambda">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %X{AWSRequestId} %t %-5p [%X{userId}] %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Lambda>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Lambda"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Lambda"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers> 
</Configuration>
```

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21937137/1039555), I added the following, but it still doesn't show the apache logs.

```
    <Logger name="org.apache.http.client" level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Lambda"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.apache.http.impl.client" level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Lambda"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.apache.http.impl.conn" level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Lambda"/>
    </Logger>
```

I can confirm that this `log4j2.xml` is being used by log4j because the logs are following the `<pattern>` I wrote.

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: As far as I can see you are using it in aws lambda. Have you followed this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html ?

Comment: @HristoAngelov yes I followed that, but currently I am just testing in my IDE. Logs should be shown in the console too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the Commons Logging Bridge dependency fixed it:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177757/1039555) for more details.